# Double values in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, unique

Is it possible to define a ID column to be unique but every value have to be occur twice?

For example:

table TRANSLATION:

```
id          | name_id | translation
____________|_________|____________
1           | 1       | apple
____________|_________|____________
2           | 1       | apfel    
____________|_________|____________
3           | 2       | pear
____________|_________|____________
4           | 2       | birne
```

I want name_id values to always occur twice, not once and not three times. name_id is a FK from table with my objects that needs to be translated.

Comment: Well if it occurs twice it is by definition not unique at all, why/what is name_id? Perhaps if you explain your need an alternative can be suggested. (You should also edit and add a tag for your specific database platform)

Comment: If the records can't occur once, how do you insert the initial record?

Comment: Cardinality check constraints can can not be defined declarative in  RDBMS's. You need to implement this kind of constraint in data integrity level, like triggers or application logic.

Comment: @DanBracuk - it's possible to insert more than one row with a single `INSERT` statement.

Comment: How do you plan to distinguish between the two rows with the same `name_id` values? Is there not some further column, i.e. a language code, such that it could just enforce that `name_id, language` is unique?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, there is but I want other solution. it is not ideal for my database

Comment: _"I want name_id values to always occur twice, not once and not three times"_ - until you add a third language. A RDBMS will let you easily define the maximum (that can grow as you add languages), but the enforcement of the minimum is a job for the application logic (stored procedures or middle-tier/client app). On the other hand, if you never intend for your database to be able to support another language, just use 2 field in objects (and you don't need the TRANSLATION table).

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean a maximum of twice? or do you mean they have to occur twice (i.e., once only is not ok) 
If the former, Once only IS ok) then you could Add a bit field and make the Primary Key composite on the actual id and the bit field.

If the latter (They *have* to occur twice), then put two id fields in the same row and make then each a single field unique key.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is impossible to *enforce*, though you can attempt it using triggers this is normally a pretty messy solution.

I'd change your table structure to be something like the following:

```
ID
NAME_ID
LANGUAGE_ID
TRANSLATION
```

You could then create a unique index on `NAME_ID` *and* `LANGUAGE_ID`. Theoretically, you'd also have a table `LANGUAGES`, and the `LANGUAGE_ID` column would have a foreign key back into `LANGUAGES.ID` - you could then restrict the number of times each `NAME_ID` appears by not having the data in `LANGUAGES`.

Ultimately this means that your schema would look something like this:

```
create table languages ( 
   id number
 , description varchar2(4000)
 , constraint pk_languages primary key (id)
   );

insert into languages values (1, 'English');
insert into languages values (2, 'German');

create table names (
   id number
 , description varchar(4000)
 , constraint pk_names primary key (id)
   );

insert into names values (1, 'apple');
insert into names values (2, 'pear');

create table translations (
   id number
 , name_id number
 , language_id number
 , translation varchar2(4000)
 , constraint pk_translations primary key (id)
 , constraint fk_translations_names foreign key (name_id) references names (id)
 , constraint fk_translations_langs foreign key (language_id) references languages (id)
 , constraint uk_translations unique (name_id, language_id)
   );

insert into translations values (1, 1, 1, 'apple');
insert into translations values (2, 1, 2, 'apfel');
insert into translations values (3, 2, 1, 'pear');
insert into translations values (4, 2, 2, 'birne');
```

and you should be unable to break the constraints:

```
SQL> insert into translations values (5, 1, 3, 'pomme');
insert into translations values (5, 1, 3, 'pomme')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (FK_TRANSLATIONS_LANGS) violated - parent
key not found


SQL> insert into translations values (5, 1, 2, 'pomme');
insert into translations values (5, 1, 2, 'pomme')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (UK_TRANSLATIONS) violated
```

See [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a44b2/1)

Comment: Yes, I have that exact solution(you can look up my other question), but it is not ideal, that's why I am looking for another solution.

Comment: in my table "names" there is more than one column to translate. and more tables, and possibliy even views of tables. my boss thinks that it can be done better.

Comment: I don't see how views or other tables change the essential design @PRO. If you've got more than one column to translate in NAMES it implies that you've denormalised that and will therefore have to normalise it or partially denormalise your TRANSLATIONS table. There is no other way to enforce this... as I say you can do achieve the same goal with triggers but it will be messy and slow.

Comment: yes, in the end your answer is correct, but i wanted to find another solution, as I said.